# JQM: how to get (only 1) selected item (on select/click) from a SELECT (multiple)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Edit : Since im new to JQM and I did not find an easy (JQM built-in) way to keep(retain) orders upon selecting items from a MULTIPLE , i broke down the algo in my mind and I think I need you to meet the question below, so I can get the users ranked picks among the items at . PS I would prefer a jqm way as much as possible.

**Main Issue** : How can I get the selected item (only 1)? Since its multiple, both `$(this).val()` and `$(this).text()` fails, after..

```
<select name="names[]" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">`
  <option>opt1</option>
  <option>opt2</option>
  <option>opt3</option>
</select>
```

i have this jQuery :

```
$('body').delegate('select','change',function(e) {
  //selected_or_clicked_item = $(this).val();
  //after selecting multiple item - returns an array of all input ['opt1','opt3','opt2']
  selected_or_clicked_item = $(this).text(); // returns all concatenated options text - opt1opt2opt3
});
```

I only get the right item at first selection (ex. opt1), after the second selection (opt2) I get both instead (['opt1','opt2'] or opt1opt2)

Comment: There is a contradiction in your question: there actually are multiple items selected. There is no concept of priority in multiple selection, so which item do you think should be the "most selected" one?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, ShovanSahu, sorry if I did not deliver my query well. Among the items (op1,opt2 ... ) from the list generated by JQM, the select html, I want (only) the item chosen by the user as per list items clicking (multiple selection). So since $this.val() and $this.text() returns all the checked/selected/clicked items, its not gonna help. Perhaps I shouldn't use the 'change' event?

Comment: Alas, there is no direct way to get the last option selected by the user (chronologically). Naveen's answer will return the first selected (hierarchically). You probably will have to track each option as it is selected in order to determine the "most recent" one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').delegate('select','change',function(e) {
      //selected_or_clicked_item = $(this).val();
      //after selecting multiple item - returns an array of all input ['opt1','opt3','opt2']
      selected_or_clicked_item = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // returns all concatenated options text - opt1opt2opt3
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work :-

$('body').delegate('select','change',function(e) {
  selected_or_clicked_item_val = $(this).find("option:selected:last").val();     
  selected_or_clicked_item_text = $(this).find('option:selected:last').text(); 
});

I have edited my answer. check this. It will solve your problem.
```

Comment: sure it would. Thanks for the answer, but i want the selected item only (only 1) (just the recent 1), its more of a 'just_got_selected_one_item variable'. i dont need all of the selected ones

Comment: Why? Give some explanation about your code, don't just post it here. I twill be better for future users with less experience

Comment: @TyrHunterI have edited my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Sorry bro, your answer had a logical error, :last will not give you the last clicked item but the farthest(last option element in the dom relative the selector) checked option element. Please check your answer very well first